# Tensorflow execution in a virtual machine with no GPUs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I had a question regarding tensorflow that is, somewhat critical to what task I'm trying to accomplish.

My scenario is as follows,
 1. I have a tensorflow script that has been set-up, trained and tested. It is working well.

2. The training and testing was done on a devBox with 2 Titan X cards.

   3. We need to now port this system to a live-pilot testing stage and are required to deploy it on a virtual-machine with Ubuntu 14.04 running atop of it.

Here lies the problem - A vm will not have access to underlying GPUs and must validate the incoming data in CPU only mode. My question,

1. Will the absence of GPUs hinder the validation process of my ML system? Does tensorflow, by default use GPUs for CNN computation and will the absence of a GPU affect the execution?
2. How do I run my script in CPU only mode?
3. Will setting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to none help with the validation in a CPU-only mode after the system has been trained on GPU boxes?

I'm sorry if this comes across as a noob question but I am new to TF and any advice would be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any further information about my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` set to empty string will make sure that you don't have anything that depends on GPU being present, and theoretically it should be enough. In practice, there are some bugs in GPU codepath which can get triggered when there are no GPUs (like [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2940#issuecomment-238952433)), so you want to make sure your GPU software environment (CUDA version) is the same.

Alternatively, you could compile TensorFlow without GPU support (`bazel build -c opt tensorflow`), this way you don't have to worry about matching CUDA environments or setting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`

Comment: Thank you very much you your clarification. I would first implement the suggestion of execution with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to null and if it fails, I would recompile using Basel and retain!